# Severe High Memory Usage (Relative)

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I am getting a Severe High Memory Usage (Relative) message from Zend Event monitor on a 2 line script which is literally:

```
<?php
 header('Location: https://www.website.com/directory/');
```

The amount of memory being used is around 720kb when the error is reported for that page.

Any ideas of things to look into? I am at a loss as to why it could be so high for script like that.

Comment: If your script is any longer than this, it shouldn't be.  What's in the rest of the script?

Comment: What is the `DocumentRoot` of `https://www.website.com/directory/`? The script you're redirecting to is going to be the cause.